# How to use access token stored in session storage for doing web api call using HttpClient?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, session-storage

I have done login using ajax call and stored the access token in session storage using following code.

```
        $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:59983/token',
                method: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    username: $('#txtUsername').val(),
                    password: $('#txtPassword').val(),
                    grant_type: 'password'
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", response.access_token);
                    console.log("Success!!!!");
                    alert("Login Successful");
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log("Failed!!!!");
                    $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                    $('#divError').show('fade');
                }
            });
        });
```

Now after login, I want to use the stored access token for performing api calls using HttpClient from a controller method. I don't know how to pass that stored access token to make api call.
The following code I have written to make api call using HttpClient.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59983/api/flight");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("flight");
            responseTask.Wait();
            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<tblFlight>>();
                readTask.Wait();
                flights = readTask.Result;
            }
            else
            {
                flights = Enumerable.Empty<tblFlight>();
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
        }
```

Please suggest me how to use that stored access token ?

Comment: sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'); 

this is method to fetch value from session storage

Comment: will it work in a method of controller for asp.net mvc project ?

Answer (score 1):

When we are dealing with webstorage such as session storage or local storage we are doing it client side using javascript , jquery etc. These storage item cannot be accessed in server side code. They are confined to your local browser and can be accessed from client side code running on browser.
            Now for your condition i think you can go for session on server side. The point where you are setting value in local storage , instead of putting there do a ajax call to any actionresult function on server and set the value in session. Later on fetch it on server side. Again if you want that value client side you need to do ajax call again and get it from server side function in controller.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so if I understand correctly, you login and create a token then from your MVC controller you want to call API endpoints and use the stored token for that.

The code you posted seems to be what exists in your MVC controller.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //here retrieve the token from where you stored it
            string accessToken = "whatever";


            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59983/api/flight");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync("flight");
            responseTask.Wait();
            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<tblFlight>>();
                readTask.Wait();
                flights = readTask.Result;
            }
            else
            {
                flights = Enumerable.Empty<tblFlight>();
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
            }
        }
```

Now, if you call the API endpoint directly from javascript then at that point you will need to have it available to your client so in theory. What you could do is store the token in client side storage as well so you can retrieve it when you need to and I can see you're already doing it on the client side.

If you need it in your MVC controller, then get it from session and pass it through to your API endpoint. In this case, you can use an initial extra call, you get your token on client side anyway so after that just call an extra MVC endpoint, pass the token to it and save it in session. This way to have it both on client side and backend side should you need that.

The MVC, Web API combo is a bit of a bastardization of everything. The reason is that MVC obviously has access to Session, while Web API is supposed to be stateless, thus no Session access. In theory a Web API endpoint which is part of an MVC application can get access to the Session object, although that is something that I would avoid doing. I prefer to keep Web API as a completely separate project but I know that's not always possible.